# How to append a custom string to "title= title" in jade?

Tags: pug

I am currently in the process of introducing myself to Jade along with node.js

As I want to avoid redundancy I thought of appending the domain name to the currect title, e.g. `Blog | example.com`

My Jade template gets the `Blog` via the Node.js router as `title`. Now I want to append `| example.com` to the title but I don't know how to do it when my template looks like this:

```
!!! 5
html(lang="de")
  head
    meta(charset="utf-8")
    title= title
```

How do I have to modify the last line so I can append the text?

I hope my question is clear enough.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The below worked for me.

```
!!! 5
html(lang="de")
  head
    meta(charset="utf-8")
    title= title + " example.com"
```

If you want to use it in the body with h1 and p tags use this:

```
body
  h1 #{title} example.com
  p #{title} example.com
```

Comment: Hell yeah, this works perfectly. Never thought of trying plain JavaScript syntax :) Thanks!